# Generic type <E> in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an implementation of the Java queue class but I have some problems.

I want the class to implement the following interface:

```
 public interface iQueue<E> {
     public void add(E e); 
 }

 public class Queue<E> implements iQueue{

     Element<E> first;

     @Override
     public void add(E e) {
         Element<E> node = new Element();
         node.setData(e);
     }
 }
```

The compiler indicates that the add method parameter must be of type Object to implement the interface

If I declare the parameter of type Object, is the type E declared when constructing the class respected?
Thank you very much

Comment: You need `public class Queue<E> implements iQueue<E> { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the type parameter in the interface:

```
public class Queue<E> implements iQueue<E> { 
  //...
}
```

By the way, according to Java convention, your interface should start with upper 
case: `IQueue<E>`